# DataAnnotations appear to not function correctly on value types using a Validator

Tags: c#, data-annotations

Why does this always return true??

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Age = 24;

            ICollection<ValidationResult> results = new Collection<ValidationResult>();
            bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(p, new ValidationContext(p, null, null), results);

            Console.WriteLine("Valid = {0}",isValid);

            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorMessage);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You have to identify yourself!!")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public decimal Age { get; set; }    

    }
```

what is wrong with my usage??

Comment: @Erik Phillips : Thanks for editing the title... makes more sense now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int` is a value type and can never be `null`.

A `new Person()` will have an `Id` of `0`, which will satisfy `[Required]`.
In general, `[Required]` is useless on value types.

To fix this, you can use a nullable `int?`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [RangeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx).  This should err when Id is `< 1`.

```
public class Person
{
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "You have to identify yourself!!")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public decimal Age { get; set; }    

}
```